# How to fix icons in AppBar when changing toolbarHeight in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

This is my app bar with one line text:

```
   appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text("Summer Trip"),
      centerTitle: true,
      actions: [
        PopupMenuButton(
          itemBuilder: (context){
            return [
              PopupMenuItem<int>(
                value: 0,
                child: Text("Test"),
              ),
            ];
          },
        ),

      ],
    ),
```

And it gives the following result:

[image]

As you see the center of the row is about 25 pixels from screen border.

Now I need to add the second line to my title. This is my solution:

```
    appBar: AppBar(
      toolbarHeight: 70,
      flexibleSpace: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                child: Text('Summer Trip',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 20.0)
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
                child: Text('Step 1',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white54, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal, fontSize: 14.0)
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      actions: [
        PopupMenuButton(
          itemBuilder: (context){
            return [
              PopupMenuItem<int>(
                value: 0,
                child: Text("Test"),
              ),
            ];
          },
        ),
      ],
    ),
```

And this is the result:

[image]

As you see, if we increase `toolbarHeight` of `AppBar` then arrow and menu buttons move down. However, I need them to stay at the same position. Could anyone say how to do it?

Comment: In the second example, you have set `toolbarHeight: 70`, that's why it's bigger

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your widgets with Align widget.

```
appBar: AppBar(
    toolbarHeight: 70,
    flexibleSpace: SafeArea(
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: const [
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
              child: Text('Summer Trip',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      fontSize: 20.0)),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
              child: Text(
                'Step 1',
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white54,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                    fontSize: 14.0),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
    leading: Align(
      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
      child: IconButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        icon: const Icon(
          Icons.arrow_back,
        ),
      ),
    ),
    actions: [
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        child: PopupMenuButton(
          itemBuilder: (context) {
            return [
              const PopupMenuItem<int>(
                value: 0,
                child: Text("Test"),
              ),
            ];
          },
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [@Pavel_K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5057736/pavel-k) for correcting me, earlier I misunderstood the question.

## Corrected Answer

Instead of using `flexibleSpace`, use `title` (for the main title) and `bottom` (for the subtitle). This approach will solve your query, and make the icons stay on top (along the center of the title).

```dart
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        toolbarHeight: 70,
        leading: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
        title: Column(
          children: const [
            Text(
              'Summer Trip',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                fontSize: 20.0,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        bottom: const PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size(0, 14),
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8),
            child: Text(
              'Step 1',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white54,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                fontSize: 14.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        actions: [
          PopupMenuButton(
            itemBuilder: (context) {
              return [
                const PopupMenuItem<int>(
                  value: 0,
                  child: Text("Test"),
                ),
              ];
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

[image]

## Old (incorrect) Answer

I think you are using the `flexibleSpace` with the incorrect intent; it is meant to be used with [FlexibleSpaceBar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FlexibleSpaceBar-class.html).

What you want to achieve can be simply achieved using `title` property of `AppBar`, and it will center the icon on it's own.

It will look like this:

```dart
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        toolbarHeight: 70,
        leading: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
        title: Column(
          children: const [
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
              child: Text(
                'Summer Trip',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
              child: Text(
                'Step 1',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white54,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                  fontSize: 14.0,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

[image: screenshot of the Page]

Comment: Yes, you are right. The same can be achieved with title: Column(). However, it doesn't answer the main question - how to fix icons position when toolbarHeight changes.

Comment: thanks @Pavel_K, earlier I misunderstood it. but now I have updated my answer :)

Comment: I also tried such solution. Try to decrease the space between title 1 and title 2 (as in picture). I couldn't. Can you?

Comment: yeah, I also coudn't. perhaps you should go with @erkaneroglu 's answer.

Comment: Please, refactor your answer. Use 4 spaces inside your code block, for correct line formatting. Decrease your image size, for better visualization.